# API to fetch logs from CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there any currently?

From what I could find, I can only process these logs by sending them through a kinesis stream or to a lambda receptor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In CloudWatch Logs, individual logs are called 'Log Events'. There are a couple of APIs that will be relevant here:

**GetLogEvents**

This API lists log events from the specified log stream. You can list all the log events or filter using a time range.

- [API - GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html)
- [CLI - get-log-events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html)
- [PowerShell - Get-CWLLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-CWLLogEvents.html)

**FilterLogEvents**

This API lists log events from the specified log group. You can list all the log events or filter the results using a filter pattern, a time range, and the name of the log stream.

This API primarily differs from GetLogEvents inthat you can use the [filterPattern](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html#CWL-FilterLogEvents-request-filterPattern) parameter to filter for all events matching some pattern, and that you can search across one or more log streams with the [logStreamNames](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html#CWL-FilterLogEvents-request-logStreamNames) parameter.

- [API - FilterLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html)
- [CLI - filter-log-events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html)
- [PowerShell - GetCWLFilteredLogEvent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-CWLFilteredLogEvent.html)

---

Both APIs maximum response size is 1MB or 10,000 logs -- whichever you hit first.  If you hit that limit and there are more logs available, the API will also respond with nextToken ([linked example for GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html#CWL-GetLogEvents-request-nextToken)). Use it to make subsequent requests to iterate through all logs that can be returned with your request.

These APIs will also have a variant in the [SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk), just search in the CloudWatch Logs section of the documentation for the SDK you need.